# How to add expiration header into my site

Tags: content-management-system

I've created my website http://www.thecabinetdepot.com, using volutions CMS.

I am facing issue of browser leverage caching during w3c validation.

How can I add expiration header into my site?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the `.htacces` file (if you're able to do it) as it is the Google recomendation you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching)

If you also want to get better score of google ranks, just follow any other steps that same page tells you. I can tell it's very usefull...